# Is a submonoid of a commutative, finitely generated monoid, always finitely generated?

Tags: semigroups, monoid, finitely-generated

Let $M$ be a commutative, finitely generated monoid and $N$ its submonoid. Is $N$ finitely generated as well?

Comment: I know I should not. But when I saw this, I thought that this was just ridiculous. How is this question off topic? What more context does one need? A simple question was asked, a simple answer was given (thanks again for that, very nice to take the time and answer other peoples questions). It was very clearly maths related. Do you guys need me to write a book on how I arrived at this question? Perhaps what I had for lunch the previous day as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let M be $Z\oplus Z$, and let N be the subset of M of those pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \geq 0$ and either $y=0$ or $x>0$.

Comment: yes that seems to infinitely generated. Thanks.